# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Befugnis und Berechtigung?

Tags: meaning, difference

Unterscheiden sich die Begriffe *Befugnis* und *Berechtigung*? Was ist der Zusammenhang?

Comment: Bei solchen Fragen wäre es hilfreich zu wissen, was Du in einem Wörterbuch gefunden hast und was genau noch unklar ist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Unterschied zwischen *Befugnis* und *Berechtigung* liegt in der Anwendbarkeit der Begriffe in bestimmten Situationen. Der Begriff *Berechtigung* kann nämlich zusätzliche Bedeutungen annehmen.

Sie sind Synonyme, sofern es um die Bedeutung „Ermächtigung“ oder „Recht, etwas zu tun“ geht:<sup>1,2</sup>

> Zur Akteneinsicht fehlt Ihnen die Ermächtigung / das Recht / die *Befugnis* / die *Berechtigung*.

Die *Berechtigung* kann zusätzlich in der Bedeutung „Rechtmäßigkeit“ auftreten:<sup>3</sup>

> Die Rechtmäßigkeit / *Berechtigung* seiner Forderung wurde anerkannt.

Zuweilen wird auch der materielle Träger des Berechtigungsnachweises, also etwa ein Nachweisschreiben, eine Urkunde oder Ähnliches, kurz als Berechtigung bezeichnet.

> Zeigen Sie mir mal die *Berechtigung*, die da aus Ihrer Taschen guckt!

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> vgl. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Befugnis), Eintrag *Befugnis*, Bedeutung 1


<sup>2</sup> vgl. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Berechtigung), Eintrag *Berechtigung*, Bedeutung 1


<sup>3</sup> vgl. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Berechtigung), Eintrag *Berechtigung*, Bedeutung 2</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Inhaltlich sehe ich da eher keinen Unterschied, sondern nur im Anwendungsgebiet.
"Befugnis" ist eher im Juristen- und Behördendeutsch üblich, bei "Berechtigung" denkt man eher an technische Bereiche ("user X hat folgende Berechtigungen: Lesen, Schreiben, Ausführen").

Answer (score 4):

Wichtig ist hier zu unterscheiden zwischen einer allgemeinsprachlichen Semantik und der behördensprachlichen Verwendung dieser Begriffe. Ich vermute stark, dass die Ausgangsfrage im Zusammenhang steht mit der Behördensprache.

**1) Allgemeinsprachlich**

Siehe die anderen Antworten auf dieser Seite

**2) Behördensprachlich**

Gesetzgeber und Behörden der Bundesrepublik Deutschland verwenden Begriffe wie

> Berechtigung
> Befugnis
> Erlaubnis
> Gestattung
> Titel
> Etc.

traditionell in einem sehr spezifischen, genau definierten Sinn zur Unterscheidung bestimmter Rechte bestimmter Personenkreise, hier insbesondere von Zuwanderern jeglicher Form, also im Zusammenhang mit den *Ausländerrecht* bzw. *Aufenthaltsrecht*.

Die exakte Bedeutung der Termini lässt sich nicht aus dem Wort selbst herleiten. Vielmehr muss man zu jedem Begriff wie Aufenthaltserlaubnis, Aufenthaltsbefugnis, Aufenthaltsgestattung, Aufenthaltsgenehmigung etc. den jeweiligen spezifischen momentan gültigen Stand der Gesetze und Regelungen kennen.

**Beispiele**

> Die **Aufenthaltsberechtigung** war nach deutschem Ausländerrecht eine Form der **Aufenthaltsgenehmigung**, die zwischen 1991 und 2004 nach dem damals geltenden Ausländergesetz (§ 27 Ausländergesetz) erteilt wurde. Sie war zeitlich und räumlich unbeschränkt.
>
> Die **Aufenthaltserlaubnis** ist ein **Aufenthaltstitel** nach dem seit dem 1. Januar 2005 in Deutschland geltenden Aufenthaltsgesetz (Kernstück des Zuwanderungsgesetzes). Sie wird zweckgebunden und befristet an sog. Drittstaatsangehörige erteilt. <sup>1</sup>

Das Bundesinnenministerium informiert zum gegenwärtigen Stand (Sept. 2018):

> Die Aufenthaltserlaubnis ist einer von insgesamt sieben Aufenthaltstiteln, die das Aufenthaltsgesetz vorsieht (Aufenthaltserlaubnis, Niederlassungserlaubnis, Daueraufenthaltserlaubnis–EU, Blaue Karte EU, ICT-Karte, Mobiler-ICT-Karte und Visum). Im Unterschied zur Niederlassungserlaubnis und Daueraufenthaltserlaubnis–EU werden Aufenthaltserlaubnis, Blaue Karte EU, ICT-Karte, Mobiler-ICT-Karte und Visum befristet erteilt. Die Erteilung erfolgt zu den im Aufenthaltsgesetz genannten Zwecken. <sup>2</sup>

**Kritik**

Die Begrifflichkeiten sind undurchsichtig und schwer zu erlernen da leicht zu verwechseln. Ich bin seit jeher dafür, das Begriffswirrwarr aufzulösen und die verschiedenen Rechtssituationen zu numerieren, wo wie man ja auch Führerscheinklassen numeriert (oder buchstabiert). Dann gäbe es Aufenthaltsrecht Klasse 1, Aufenthaltsrecht Klasse 2, Aufenthaltsrecht Klasse 3... (oder statt Klasse gerne auch Stufe oder Typ), und das Leben von Zuwanderern, Juristen und Beamten wäre ein bisschen einfacher.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Beide Absätze kopiert aus den entsprechenden Wikipedia-Einträgen, 18.9.2018. Hervorhebungen von mir.]

<sup>2</sup> https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/migration/aufenthaltsrecht/aufenthaltsrecht-liste.html

<sup>3</sup> Aus dem invarianten Auftreten von "Erlaubnis" im Zitat von der Website des Bundesinnenministeriums könnte man schließen, dass die Innenbehörden inzwischen von dem traditionellen Erlaubnis-Gestattung-Genehmigung-Befugnis-Etc.-Wirrwar Abstand nehmen und jetzt versuchen, in der Tat nur noch Zusammenfügungen mit "-erlaubnis" zu bilden, die dann durch das vorgestellte Bestimmungswort leichter zu entschlüsseln sind. Das ist aber jetzt nur eine Vermutung.

Comment: @Don Christian Cuijote - Zum Punkt "Kritik": Ich wünsche Dir viel Erfolg dabei, schätze die Aussichten indes als nicht sehr groß ein... ;-)

Comment: @Volker - Wo du eine Windmühle siehst, stürme sie!